# using kohana zend lucene search

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, kohana

i have a kohana-based website, and i want to use zend-lucene search.

as i have seen in the documentation here https://github.com/evopix/kohana-search/blob/master/README.markdown but i do not understand: must i re-create the models i already have in order to be able to use it? the model should extend the ORM_Searchable (it is a must)? and where can i find the ORM_Searchable class in kohana?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to recreate the models. You extend from a new class, implement its methods which specify what data you want to be indexed by Zend Lucene. The documentation is really straight forward.

> the model should extend the ORM_Searchable (it is a must)? and where can i find the ORM_Searchable class in kohana?

This is in the code repository you linked to. [classes/kohana/orm/searchable.php](https://github.com/evopix/kohana-search/blob/master/classes/kohana/orm/searchable.php)